# Why doesn't the first ModelFormSet pick up the id from request.POST?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to add multiple of a ModelForm using the ModelFormSetFactory.  Upon submission the first of the set returns an error saying "(Hidden field id) This field is required." even though the hidden id field is in the form.  For any further forms in this set, this error does not occur and the id can be found in the cleaned_data.

The view for this form (in views.py):

```py
class NewRecipeView(generic.TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ingredient_data = {
                'ingredient-TOTAL_FORMS': '0',
                'ingredient-INITIAL_FORMS': '1',
        }
        context = {"new_page": "active",
                   "form": RecipeForm(),
                   "formset_ingredient": RecIngFormSet(ingredient_data, prefix="ingredient"),
        }
        return render(request, 'recipes/new_recipe.html', context)

    def post(self, request):
        form = RecipeForm(request.POST)
        formset_ingredient = RecIngFormSet(request.POST, prefix="ingredient")
        print(request.POST)
        for fs in formset_ingredient:
            print(fs)
            print(fs.cleaned_data)
        if form.is_valid() and formset_ingredient.is_valid():
            new_rec = form.save(commit=False)
            new_rec.created_at = timezone.now()
            new_rec.save()
            for fs in formset_ingredient:
                new_rec_ing = fs.save(commit=False)
                new_rec_ing.recipe = new_rec
                new_rec_ing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('recipes:recipe', args=(new_rec.id,)))
        else:
            print('handle invalid forms here')
```

And the actual form in forms.py:

```py
class RecipeIngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RecipeIngredient
        fields = ['quantity', 'unit', 'ingredient']


recIngFormSet = modelformset_factory(RecipeIngredient, RecipeIngredientForm)
```

In the HTML I am building the form from `{{ formset_ingredient.empty_form }}` with javascript and making sure that I follow the rules set in `{{ formset_ingredient.management_form }}`.  I think this bit is fine as the POST looks good (to me), I think it's just the handling of the POST that is the issue.

An example of the request.POST is:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['rMETmq9lkOnN5Nmath3pOa2m2YjMWYWTqcNY7MIcdrbUDUkLxKwcNqZHIrE9iWj2'], 'name': ['Rec Name'], 'serves': ['1'], 'ingredient-TOTAL_FORMS': ['2'], 'ingredient-INITIAL_FORMS': ['1'], 'ingredient-MIN_NUM_FORMS': [''], 'ingredient-MAX_NUM_FORMS': [''], 'ingredient-0-quantity': ['1'], 'ingredient-0-unit': ['lb'], 'ingredient-0-ingredient': ['1'], 'ingredient-0-id': [''], 'ingredient-1-quantity': ['2'], 'ingredient-1-unit': ['lb'], 'ingredient-1-ingredient': ['2'], 'ingredient-1-id': [''], 'ingredient-__prefix__-quantity': [''], 'ingredient-__prefix__-unit': [''], 'ingredient-__prefix__-ingredient': [''], 'ingredient-__prefix__-id': ['']}>
```

Django then converts the prefixed formset 'ingredient' to `{'quantity': Decimal('1'), 'unit': '1', 'ingredient': <Ingredient: orange>}` and `{'quantity': Decimal('2'), 'unit': 'lb', 'ingredient': <Ingredient: banana>, 'id': None}`
The issue is that I think the first one should also have `'id': None`.

I appreciate any help you can give.  If you need more information or code snippets, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read a bit more into FormSets and FormSetFactories and the issue was just that I didn't read the docs thoroughly enough.

The following line creates a formset with one form inside it by default:

```py
RecNoteFormSet = modelformset_factory(RecipeNote, RecipeNoteForm)
```

So there is no need to define the management form configuration like I did here:

```py
        ingredient_data = {
                'ingredient-TOTAL_FORMS': '0',
                'ingredient-INITIAL_FORMS': '1',
        }
```

I'm still not 100% sure on why my request wasn't being read correctly, but now that I am using more Django functionality and relying less on javascript to build my form on the frontend, this issue is solved.